# Spigot/Bukkit Plugin: How to Me Check Item in Player Right Hand? - Minecraft

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Exaple of answer:

```
if(player has clicked && item in player right hand is stick) {
   // Do some action
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use PlayerInteractEvent.

```
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerUse(PlayerInteractEvent event){
        Player p = event.getPlayer();
        if(p.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.BLAZE_ROD){
            // Code goes here
        }
    }
```

Also don't forget to register your listener in onEnable method.